# Converting an Eclipse Java project into an SVN project?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn, subclipse

So I am trying to do something slightly unusual.
I checked out a project using Tortoise SVN, and then I imported that project into Eclipse as a Java project, and I can build the project fine.

But I would much rather use Eclipse's Subversion plugin than Tortoise SVN to check in files, update, compare diff's etc.

So is there any way I hook that Java project back into SVN in Eclipse, and then be able to check in files etc through Eclipse.

Note that checking out the project again using Eclipse is not an option for a few different reasons.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the Project and select 'Team > Share Project...' to set up SVN on the project.